# Improving performance of Contour rendering using OpenGL?

Tags: performance, opengl, graphics, rendering, opengl-3

Please refer to [the video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GcjJtgoXgn8).

In my application, I display stack of contours using  a DisplayList created using GL_LINE_STRIP.

User can select contour lines using mouse . For that ,before rendering the DisplayList, I render  all contours using an unique color and read the pixel-color under the mouse .(as explained [here](http://www.gpwiki.org/index.php/OpenGL_Selection_Using_Unique_Color_IDs)) .This rendering is 
done using "immediate mode".

User can also move,delete selected contours.In that case ,I regenerate the DisplayList.

My questions are:

1) I am using old OpenGL techniques .(fixed pipe-line architecture.) Is there any ways to improve the performance using new OpenGL techniques ? (using GPU,shaders...etc)
    Because for large number of contours,the operations are not smooth.

2) I think the "immediate mode" rendering done for contour selection is also  a performance panelty.Is there any better way to do this ?

3) I need to display contour nodes as a point-cloud ,using GL_POINTS.In this ,I should create another DisplayList using GL_POINTS? (that means there are two DisplayLists; one when diaplaying lines , other for displaying points)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving away from display lists and switching to [vertex arrays (VAs)](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Arrays) or [vertex buffer objects (VBOs)](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Buffer_Object) should give you a decent speed-up.

You can *very* easily switch between `GL_LINE_STRIP` and `GL_POINTS` by changing the first argument to [`glDrawArrays()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawArrays.xml).  No need for two copies of your geometry.

Comment: Correct, don't use display lists.

Comment: in VA case, number of calls to graphics card will be number of contour-lines.(each contour is drawn using one glDrawArrays() API call).But in DisplayList case,the entire drawing-calls are compiled and stored in graphics-card command-buffer and just one API call needed.So how  can VA can be better than DisplayList?